# Развратить и совратить.

Tags: глаголы, семантика

Как могло случиться, что эти антонимы употребляются в качестве синонимов?
Ведь *совратить* явно означает *свернуть то, что было развёрнуто*.
Очевидно, некогда существовала возможность вернуть человеку ЦЕЛомудрие, ЦЕЛостность, исЦЕЛить его...
Хотелось бы узнать, какие будут мнения по данному вопросу. )))

Answer (score 5):

Совратить - это заставить человека свернуть человека с правильного пути, по которому он шел. Развратить - значит предложить ему множество разных искушений (значение приставки РАЗ - направить действие в разные стороны), это как бы предельное падение изначально нравственного индивидуума.

Comment: Хорошо, но как тогда назвать обратный процесс наставления на путь истинный? Одним словом с тем же корнем?

Comment: Наверное, это "возвращение" к истинным ценностям. Вообще говоря, слова с приставками  СО и РАЗ не всегда являются антонимами, как, например: свернуть скатерть - развернуть скатерть, сойтись - разойтись. В этих примерах приставка СО имеет значение совмещения, а приставка РАЗ - значение разъединения, расхождения. Слова совратить/развратить - это как раз не антонимы. Здесь приставка СО аналогична приставке С в глаголе "свернуть (повернуть)", где значение направления имеет сам глагол, а приставка обозначает доведения действия до результата.

Comment: Это  что,  условие  такое,  чтобы  одним  словом  с  тем  же  корнем ?

Comment: Я хотела бы сообщить дополнительную информацию о приставке  РАЗ (по словарю Ефремовой).Ее общее значение - это направить действие в разные стороны, но на основе этого значения развиваются дополнительные значения, в частности "совершить действие с большой интенсивностью: хвалить - расхвалить, толстеть - растолстеть. думаю, что это значение приставки походит для нашего случая.

Comment: вратить - развратить?

Answer (score 2):

Совратить - заставить уклониться, вместе уйти в сторону от правильного пути, повернуть в плохую сторону.

СО-вместе +  вратить-повернуть

Развратить - принудительно развернуть  в направлении, противоположном от «правильного».Раз -обратное действие (разбинтовать, разминировать, развернуться)
 В церковно-славянском развраща́ть означало "уводить прочь от пути истины".

Свернуть с пути и развернуться в обратную сторону в прямом смысле не синонимы, действия разные, а вот в переносном получилось почти одинаково: уж если свернул с  истинного пути, то попадёшь точно на безнравственный, другого не дано.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, слово "воротить" - это не разворот в неправильном направлении относительно правильного. Есть словосочетание "наворотить делов", что значит, сделать что-либо плохое, причём серьёзное и значительное, здесь "наворотить" происходит от ворошить, а ворошить - рушить, нарушать, разрушать. Разврат, развращение ведёт к разрушению правил приличия, норм поведения, и, как следствие, - личности. Но почему слово "наворотить" имеет чёткий негативный  оттенок? Всё дело в том, что оно одного корня со словом "врать". Враньё же, является одним из тяжких грехов.  Так вот, совратить - значит приобщить ко греху, научить греху. А развратить - это содействовать раскрытию греха, его процветанию. 
   В итоге, какой можно сделать вывод? - Эти слова не антонимы и не синонимы. Они, как, урок и обучение, просто следуют друг за другом, разврат - это звено цепи(если, не сама цепь), следующее за совращением.